# Dynamic filtering with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

For all numeric fields in a shiny app I am adding dynamically a slider. Now I want to add also
a dynamic filter for the data based on the slider input.

To illustrate the problem some code with data and static filtering:

```
library(glue)
library(tidyverse)
data <-
  tibble(
    a = c(61, 7, 10, 2, 5, 7, 23, 60),
    b = c(2, 7, 1, 9, 6, 7, 3, 6),
    c = c(21, 70, 1, 4, 6, 2, 3, 61)
  )

input <- list("a" = c(2, 10),
              "b" = c(7, 10),
              "c" = c(1, 5))


data %>% filter(
  between(a, input$a[1], input$a[2]),
  between(b, input$b[1], input$b[2]),
  between(c, input$c[1], input$c[2])
)
```

Is there a way to implement dynamic filtering?

Comment: am i missing something or misunderstood your question? The filter() you have works.. and as long as you pass it to a reactive object, your app will be updated instantly

Comment: Yes. Indeed it works. However I want add the sliders and the filters dynamically to the shiny app for all numeric fields. Adding the sliders is straightforward, however dynamic filtering is tricky. I have a solution now, but do you know a more dpylr-like way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built myself a dynamic filter, which basically works:

```
query <- data %>% filter_if(is.numeric) %>% colnames() %>% map( function(feature){
  "between({
    feature
  }, input${
    feature
  }[1], input${
    feature
  }[2])" %>% glue()
}) %>% paste0(collapse = ", ")

eval(parse(text = "data %>% filter({
  query
})" %>% glue()))
```

Is there are a dplyr way?